# What's the most efficient way to pause during a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have a script which loops through the elements of a list. Each element is used to query an API. However, the API has a query limit (only 500 queries are permitted over a 24 hour period). I am currently managing this through a counter in a loop, which resets for each "chunk" of 500 elements and would pause the loop for a day. Is there a better way to do this?

```
counter = 0
for query in queries:
    if counter < 500:
        counter = counter + 1
        api = ApiClient(api_key='secretkey')
        data = api.get(q=query)
        print(data)
        safequery = ''.join(e for e in query if e.isalnum())
        datafilename = "{} {}.txt".format(safequery,todaysdate)
        with open(datafilename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
    else:
        print('sleepy time')
        time.sleep(86400)
        counter = 0
```

Comment: Is there a strong reason to wait for a full day in the middle of the process? this doesn't seem the best idea as the process waits for a very long time. An option is to ensure the data (queries) is partitioned or configurable to be resumed, and then run the program once per day and exit when done processing queries of the day. Some sort of scheduling job running would trigger the job every day (cron or systemd timers are common solutions on Linux based systems).

Comment: @farzad OP needs to wait so they don't hit the API quota

Comment: Your logic is a bit off - every 500th query gets skipped, in addition to triggering the sleep.  You want only the sleep (and the counter reset) to be done conditionally, the actual query should be unconditional.

Answer (score 2):

`time.sleep(86400)` is asking for problems, and also makes your CPU work for nothing. If something happens during those 86400 seconds and the script crashes, nothing will restart it.

The much better option would be to save the current page/chunk somewhere (raw text file, json, DB, doesn't really matter), then load it before making the next requests.

Then you can put your script in an **Operating System level/managed task scheduler** (for example, cron for Unix or Task Scheduler for Windows) and run it daily.

Comment: But then how do I capture "where" in the list the last query left off. I would need it to resume querying from after the last element in the list?

Comment: @OwaisArshad Like I wrote, just store in the a file/DB and load it when you next execute

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep()` is a good solution, but you can also make Python ask for input when you want to continue. That's primitive, I know.

```py
if counter % 500 == 0: # make the counter start at 1
        val = input("\nContinue? [y/n]: ")
        if val == 'y':
            pass # manually unpause the looping, whenever you want
        elif val == 'n':
            break # interrupt for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this by creating a script that when ran will get the next 500 and then terminate. You might want to output a text file to store where you are up to in this sequence.

I would then schedule this script to run every 24 hours with windows task scheduler (on windows)

This means you are not having a process running doing nothing.

```
sleep()
```

should only be used for small time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make this code as a python script and execute in a batch file.

catch this batch file and schedule into a task manager to run every day at 2:00 pm for example...

usually i have a python script server that runs my robots and things that i need to do automatically.

Answer (score -1):

An if else statement with a sleep is probably as simple as it gets; however it's not efficient since the process will still be alive and doing nothing for 86400 seconds.

You could look into creating a [cron](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/) job to run your code one a day at the same time